# Creating teams via /teams suddenly ignores visibility:Private and creates Public Team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Just noticed that teams created via https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams with "Visibility": "Private" in the request Body are now beeing created as Public Teams?!. Anyone else experiencing this? Worked just fine until a couple of days ago.

Comment: If it's a prod/corp environment, then i would first check with my administrator whether they did any policies in recent times or not. If i am not wrong, they have an option for this, as part of governance.

Comment: @Dev Do you mean Team policies, or what type of policies could affect this behaviour?

Comment: In the admin center, select Teams > Manage teams > Each team is backed by a M365 Groups > it will show you the list of properties > look for Privacy - this decides the Visibility/AccessType of the backing Microsoft 365 group!!

Comment: Also on the team's profile page, you can change the following elements of a team including "privacy" - it helps you to set whether the team is public or private. The changes that you make to a team are logged. If you're modifying group settings (changing the name, description, photo, privacy, classification, or team members), the changes are attributed to you through the audit pipeline. If you're performing actions against Teams-specific settings, your changes are tracked and attributed to you in the General channel of the team.

Comment: In addition to isolate the code outside of your application, you can try the same API call with Microsoft Graph Explorer or POSTMAN and see if you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: The same issue reported here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64879661/creating-teams-via-teams-suddenly-ignores-visibilityprivate-and-creates-public

Comment: We are able to reproduced the Issue and raised a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is an issue that started in our live environment on Nov 2nd effecting a Power Automate Flow that uses beta API to create Teams and set them to private.

A monitoring script we have that checks for any Teams that have been set to public and reverts them to private automatically every 15 minutes (due to our policies) started catching newly created teams that should be private being created as public.

This was intermittent at first but has increased in frequency this last week until nearly all , and now seemingly all, new teams don't get set to private.

I have run manual tests via graph apis beta and V1.0 and also with a  recreation of our Flow (with both beta and V1 api) to create 10 teams in succession. This at first (around 7 days ago) only failed 2 or 3 times out of 10 attempts but today fails on 100%.   I can reproduce this behaviour in 3 different tenants. Microsoft Partner colleagues have reported they know of others experiencing the same. It is without a doubt broken, at least in various tenants (all the ones Ive tried).

Im testing to see if the new Create Team action in PowerAutomate experiences the same problem and will rewrite the flow to use that if not. It that is not successful I will be logging a ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: Ok, seems then that I'm not alone in this. Please keep us posted on your tests with Create Team action (I suppose this action uses Graph behind the scenes?) or if you log a ticket I'm very intrested in the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

@boliviab Please log a ticket with Microsoft as this is serious issue.